# Show Input Text After Choose Combobox

Tags: combobox

I have an question about how to show text field based on choose combobox.
I have an code like this :

```
<select name="comment">
<option value="">Choose One</option>
<option value="Good">Good</option>
<option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
```

If I choose others, then I want text input show.

How can I do that ? Is that can be done without jquery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **Plain JavaScript**, try this
**HTML Portion**

```
<select name="comment" id="combo" onChange="check();">
<option value="">Choose One</option>
<option value="Good">Good</option>
<option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
<input type = "text" id ="dummyText" visible="false" style="visibility:hidden"/>
```

**Javascript Portion**

```
function check() {
    var el = document.getElementById("combo");
    var str = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;
    if(str == "Others") {
        show();
    }else {
        hide();
    }

}
function hide(){
    document.getElementById('dummyText').style.visibility='hidden';
}
function show(){
    document.getElementById('dummyText').style.visibility='visible';
}
```

Check [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/29sVC/2/)